# Django Template

Tags: django, templates, django-context

I am doing a Django tutorial on Templates. I am currently at this code:

```
from django.template import Template, Context
>>> person = {'name': 'Sally', 'age': '43'}
>>> t = Template('{{ person.name }} is {{ person.age }} years old.')
>>> c = Context({'person': person})
>>> t.render(c)
u'Sally is 43 years old.'
```

What I don't understand is this line:

```
c = Context({'person': person})
```

Do both variables need to be called person to be used in this example or is it just random?

What is `'person'` referring to and what is `person` referring to?

Comment: You really should do an introductory Python tutorial before attempting to learn Django.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c = Context({'person': person})
```

The first person (within quotes) denotes the variable name that the `Template` expects. The second person assigns the `person` variable created in the second line of your code to the *person* variable of the `Context` to be passed to the `Template`. The second one can be anything, as long as it matches with its declaration.

This should clarify things a little bit:

```
from django.template import Template, Context
>>> someone = {'name': 'Sally', 'age': '43'}
>>> t = Template('{{ student.name }} is {{ student.age }} years old.')
>>> c = Context({'student': someone})
>>> t.render(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Do both variables need to be called person to be used in this example or is it just random?

No, this is just random.

> What is 'person' refering to and what is person refering to?

First, the `{}` is a dictionary object, which is the python terminology for an associative array or hash. It is basically an array with (almost) arbitrary keys.

So in your example, `'person'` would be the key, `person` the value.

When this dictionary gets passed to the template, you can access your *real* objects (here, the person, with name, age, etc) by using the key, you choose before.

As an alternative example:

```
# we just use another key here (x)
c = Context({'x': person})

# this would yield the same results as the original example
t = Template('{{ x.name }} is {{ x.age }} years old.')
```

Answer (score 0):

`{'person': person}` is a standard Python [dict](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). The `Context` constructor takes a dict and produces a context object suitable for use in a template. The `Template.render()` method is how you pass the context to the template, and receive the final result.

Answer (score 0):

c = Context({'person': person})
Here the first 'person' in dictionary is variable name(key) where as other person represent the variable which you have declared in above line i.e.
 t = Template('{{ student.name }} is {{ student.age }} years old.')
**Context** is a constructor,that takes one optional argument & its a dictionary mapping variable names to variable values. Call the Template object’s render() method with the context to “fill” the template:
to get more information visit given link
http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html